# Background image in css being resized

Tags: html, css

I have this css code, that creates an triangle and an background image fixed:

```
.post-wrapper_pic2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 922px;
    height: 1550px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
background: url("http://krishnaeverson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/universe.png") center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    z-index:10px;


}
```

But the problem is that the image is beeing resized and even though i put a hight quality image as background it appears pixelated. Can you figure what's wrong in what I'm doing?

Comment: So you are wondering that a CSS property named background-_size_ leads to resizing of the image …?

Comment: not exaclty, just the image is a large image, and somehow with this code, that image is beeing resized, i'll post some pics... a minute....

Comment: We don’t need any picture here … but _you_ need to go and look up what `background-size: cover` does.

Comment: wow, that's it, realy thanks, since thats the correct answer if u want just answer with what you said :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were apparently wondering that a CSS property named background-*size* leads to resizing of the image … so you should’ve just looked up what it does.

[background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> cover
>   This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.